# Determining whether a word is a noun or not

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

Given an input word, I want to determine whether it is a noun or not (in case of ambiguity, for instance `cook` can be a noun or a verb, the word must be identified as a noun).

Actually I use the POS tagger from the Stanford Parser (i give it a single word as input, and i extract only the POS tag from the result). The results are quite good but it takes a very long time.

Is there a way (in python, please :) to perform this task quicker than what I do actually?

Comment: the stanford parser performs a lot of other things on the input (dependency parsing, constituency parsing...), it's a waste of time here. Moreover, isn't POS tagging a bit too stronger for what I want to do (usually POS tagging is performed on a whole sentence, not a single word) ?

Answer (score 15):

If you simply want to check whether or not a single word can be used as a noun, the quickest way might be to build a set of all nouns and then just check the word for membership of that set.

For a list of all nouns you could use the [WordNet](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) corpus (which can be accessed through NLTK for example):

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> nouns = {x.name().split('.', 1)[0] for x in wn.all_synsets('n')}
>>> "cook" in nouns
True
>>> "and" in nouns
False
```

Comment: it's a possibility, thank you :) nltk provides 67176 nouns, don't we lose a lot of them (use another dictionary)? (i think you forgot a `()` after `name` in your code)

Comment: You could be right: I'm not sure how many English nouns there are! You might be able to find a bigger list elsewhere to expand on what WordNet provides. (`.name`, without the parentheses, seems to be the correct way to access the word on my version of Python and NLTK.)

Comment: I believe `name` is a function, and the code should read `nouns = {x.name().split('.', 1)[0]  [...]}`

Comment: Thanks @Wallacoloo; looks like `name` changed from an attribute to a method since I wrote this answer. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the Python wrapper, but if you use the Stanford `POS tagger` rather than the parser, it should be much quicker. There are wrappers for `Stanford CoreNLP`, which includes the tagger: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/corenlp-python; or, it looks like `nltk` has a Stanford tagger module too http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html .

You may also get better results if you embed the single word in a toy sentence. Something like "The X is a thing." Depending on the sentence, this can bias you towards or away from guessing words as nouns too.

Answer (score 0):

I would second the use of Wordnet if you are checking single words. I also used the freely available TreeTagger: http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/ The binary runs really fast and has support for multiple languages.
If you need a pure Pythonic solution, check the  NLTK implementation of the Brill Tagger: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/brill.html